# Array vs In-Memory database

Tags: arrays, scala, h2, in-memory-database

I am building a REST API where I need to save 2D data (x: Double, y: Double) in application memory (no need to persist the data on disk). The no of records/data objects can grow/shrink in future. The user can add/remove data objects, but can't edit them. I have 2 choices. Either save the data ain n array/collection or use an in memory database such as H2.

The question is, which approach should I choose and why? Here is what I know already or have found until this point. Feel free to disagree and share your thoughts.

- Arrays reserve a contiguous block of memory. The data access might be faster. However, if the data grows bigger, finding a contiguous block of memory might be difficult.
- In functional programming, if a function adds/removes elements in Array/collection, it is changing the application state or in other words, it produces a side effect. This is not desirable as parallelizing this function might be difficult.
- Concurrent updates: If multiple requests are updating the array, we might end up having inconsistent data or some updates might be lost, due to race conditions. Thus, one needs to implement locking mechanism for updates. In database(relational), you can use transactions that should solve this problem. On the other side, relational databases support transactions, which should take care of inconsistency problem.

What am I missing here, does saving the data in database bring any other advantage?
Creating a database which will contain only 1 table with 2-3 columns seams to be an overkill though.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [concurrent Maps](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/concrete-mutable-collection-classes.html#concurrent-maps) which provides atomic operations and

> can be accessed by several threads at once

for example

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

case class User(id: Int, name: String)
val chm: collection.concurrent.Map[Int, User] = new ConcurrentHashMap[Int, User]().asScala
chm.addOne(1 -> User(1, "Picard"))
```

Another option is to wrap mutable state with [Akka Actor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/jmm.html#actors-and-shared-mutable-state) which guarantees

> processing of one message happens before processing of the next
>   message by the same actor

perhaps something like so

```
class MyActor() extends Actor {
  private val _mutableSate = mutable.Map[Int, User]()

  def insertUser(u: User): Unit = _mutableSate.addOne(u.id, u)
}
```

Regarding whether one should use collection or in-memory database, IMO, this is  an engineering decision which has tradeoffs but no clear answers. For example, one could apply [principle of minimal power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) reasoning and say if collections solve the problem adequately then there is no need to go with more powerful database solution. On the other hand, one should also consider does the solution scale. For example, will collections have sufficiently expressive querying mechanism once there are multiple tables which need to be joined?

Answer (score 3):

1. Arrays won't work anyway (you can't change their size), only collections will. So point 1 may not be relevant, depending on what type of collection you use.
2. This is not different between collections and databases.
3. The important question here is what your transactions look like. If they are just adding/removing a single element, you don't really need locks, just pick a concurrent collection (look under "Concurrent collections" in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html; unfortunately the standard library doesn't cover all use-cases).
4. Another question is how you want to query/access your data, whether you can benefit from indices on some of the columns (which the database supports but collections don't), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Good answers here, already, so far. Alexey's point #4, especially. I'd go a step further and suggest that you look for an in-memory database that offers geo-spatial indexing (e.g. an r-tree index), since you say your data is 2D and being able to perform spatial queries might be of some value.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using akka cluster sharding region to avoid memory lock for concurrent update.
2. Suggest to use 3rd party mem. Example Caffeine. It can help you control the size, LRU, expiration. Scala has a Caffeine wrapper named Scaffeine.

```
  val profileDocumentCache: Cache[String, T] =
    Scaffeine()
      .recordStats()
      .expireAfterWrite(1.hour)
      .maximumSize(1024)
      .build[String, T]()
```